# List/view formatting on grouped view on modern SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I am working on migrating a page from classic page to a modern page. Today I am displaying several summary links web parts as tabs (Hillbilly tabs) on a classic page. In each summary link tab I am showing the links for a specific category/project with a nice formatting. So the user just clicks the desired tab to have access to the correct links.

In order to migrate this function I have created a modern list, with the columns `Project`, `Item Link` and `Link Type`. Then I created a view where I grouped the list by Project. So the modern page is now displaying a modern list which looks like this:

> -> Project : aaa (6)
>
> -> Project : bbb (9)
>
> -> Project : ccc (5)

I do not think an end-user would understand how to use this, especially not with a confusing number last... The counting of the links is nobody interested in in this case.

With the new list/view formatting capabilities of SharePoint, I have seen that it is possible to present list items as cards and I thought that this is probably the closest to a tabbed view that I can get in our new SharePoint environment with a modern page.

So the idea is to present the projects as cards and displaying the links in groups or with different pictures depending on their types.

I have browsed the examples at https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-list-formatting/ but most of the examples seem to do formatting on lists on the item level. How can I use the examples if I have a grouping aspect in my list? I mean if I have 6 links in project "aaa" then I do not want to show the project name 6 times (on 6 different cards), which will be the case if formatting is done item-by-item. I would like to have the project name as the title of the card and then all links associated with this project listed on the card.
Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: I tried a solution with "dynamic list filtering". That could be an option if only it was possible to limit the user to select only one filter at a time.

Comment: Using Ms Forms would be an option if the user´s selection to the question about "Project" would display or launch a page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to accomplish Hillybilly like tabs in modern sharepoint currently, but this is doable by creating custom webparts via [spfx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part).

Option 2 is if creating a webpart from scratch is somewhat overkill, modern sharepoint is programmed to load less / load only contents that changed, you can try creating a tiles show it more like a tab then put the link in every page, that page will have a list that shows a different views.) so it shows like a tab but in the back its on the other page, just make sure to put the same tiles as in the other pages to make it look identical. Notice the page loads fast that it somewhat looks like its tabbed.

Hope the concept helps! Happy Learning!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, json formatting can not achieve your requirements. You could try to use spfx to create Hillbilly tabs web part.

I find this Modern Hillbilly tabs web part in GitHub, hope that will be helpful:

https://github.com/mrackley/ModernHillbillyTabs/tree/master/HipsterTabs

Comment: Do I need to install anything that requires tenant admin rights to be able to use spfx? I only have site collection admin rights. If something needs to be installed on tenant level I will need to order that work and specify exactly what needs to be done on the tentant and hope that the order will be approved by the tenant owner.

Comment: I just got a response from the tenant owner that enabling the "app catalog" is not allowed in our tenant. So I will not be able to try if the spfx solution works.